# Ansible lineinfile duplicates lines

Tags: ansible, devops

```
 - vars:
   npm:
      npm_global: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.npm-global"

 - name: Update Bashrc for npm
   lineinfile: >
   dest={{ project.shell_rc_file }}
   regexp='export PATH={{ npm.npm_global }}/bin:$PATH'
   line='export PATH={{ npm.npm_global }}/bin:$PATH'
   state=present
   backup=yes
   create=yes
```

I tried many times but always get the duplicates line in `export PATH=...`

Comment: What are you trying to do? May be you misunderstood the regexp parameter. What is your ansible version?

Comment: What does your bashrc look like before you run that play, what are you expecting it to look like and what are you actually getting?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to escape `\$` in the `regexp` parameter since `$` in regex means end of line. Your regex will never be matched since there can't be a string `PATH` after the end of line.